# SQL workflow for request for change

Tags: sql, database, workflow

I am a fresh DBA, and we are trying to design a database for a workflow engine. I need help to understand how to build a good one. Our application is a request for change. So our user submit a request to change specific things. this process needs to go through the team leader, team development, then to product owner.

Answer (score 0):

check this site :

[link1](https://exceptionnotfound.net/designing-a-workflow-engine-database-part-8-complete-schema-and-shortcomings/)
[link2](https://exceptionnotfound.net/designing-a-workflow-engine-database-part-1-introduction-and-purpose/)

i hope this Efficient

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the workflow I saw too big for what I need

Comment: @D.Jhon https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tutorial-step-database-design-sql-david-mccaldin check questuion here